# What does it mean to deviate macroscopically from the mean? And what does it mean to deviate in terms of fluctuations?

Tags: probability-theory, large-deviation-theory

Let $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables. Suppose that $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ fulfills certain regularity conditions described below. The random variables $X_{n}$ are independent and have finite means $\mathbb{E}(X_{n})$. In addition, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\rm var}(X_{n})<\infty$ and ${\rm var}(X_{n})=\sigma^2>0$ for at least one $n$.

> **QUESTION 1.** What does it mean to say that the sum $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}}{N}$ deviates from its mean $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}}{N}\right) $ *macroscopically* when $N\to\infty$? Does the term *macroscopically* have to do with some sequence of functions associated with the sequence of random variables $\{X_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ being equicontinuous? Or does the term *macroscopically* have a statistical meaning or some physical meaning (coming from statistical mechanics)?  Or is it just arbitrary terminology?

> **QUESTION 2.** What does it mean to say that the sum $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}}{N}$ deviates from its mean $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}}{N}\right)$ at the *level of fluctuations* when $N\to\infty$? Does it make any intuitive sense in terms of some sequence of graphs of the distribution functions $F_{S_{N}}$? Here $S_{N}= \frac{\sum_{n=1}^{N}X_{n}}{N}$.

This question came up after I watched the [first lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnDNZD4P_aQ&list=PLo4jXE-LdDTTp2P9aXQVbJfGrzCCbK4WI) ( 03:50 to 04:15) on YouTube of the Probability II course taught by Professor Algustus Quadros Teixeira in 2020 at IMPA. I'm not a student at IMPA.  I'm just watching  the class yesterday. The lessons are not in English.

**My attempt.** It seems to me that the two expressions *"deviating from the average macroscopically"* and *"deviating from the average in terms of fluctuations"* have everything to do with the principle of large deviations.  I looked for lecture notes and pdf materials on the internet that could explain these two expressions, such as [this material](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4146.pdf) from ArXiV.  But I couldn't find them in any of the materials I searched for on the internet

Perhaps I wasn't able to correctly translate the expression from Portuguese into English. Please correct me if I have made any inaccuracies

Comment: Intuitively (without looking at the references) I would guess that "macroscopic deviations" are those deviations from the mean of order $\Theta(N)$, while "in terms of fluctuations" are those deviations from the mean of order $O(\sqrt N)$.